# How to serialize non-static child class of static class

Tags: c#, serialization, static-classes

I want to serialize a pretty ordinary class, but the catch is it's nested in a static class like this:

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    [Serializable]
    public class SomeType
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This code:

```
StaticClass.SomeType obj = new StaticClass.SomeType();
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(obj));
```

Produces this error:

```
StaticClass.SomeType cannot be serialized. Static types cannot be used as parameters or return types.
```

That error seems completely irrelevant; `StaticClass.SomeType` is not a static type.

Is there a way around this? Am I wrong to think this error is dumb?

Comment: btw, `[Serializable]` doesn't add anything here - `XmlSerializer` doesn't use it.

Comment: It has already been reported on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/523204/class-that-is-nested-in-static-class-cannot-be-xml-serialized

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a pragmatic workaround - don't mark the nesting type `static`:

```
public class ContainerClass
{
    private ContainerClass() { // hide the public ctor
        throw new InvalidOperationException("no you don't");
    }

    public class SomeType
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: as a workaround to the XmlSerializer limitation, this is the most practical for me. thanks :)

Comment: +1 simple and effective. If I was going to do this I'd also marked the class as sealed. Reminds me of the old .NET 1 days (sealed class and private constructor)

Answer (score 4):

It's know [limitation in XmlSerializer](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/523204/class-that-is-nested-in-static-class-cannot-be-xml-serialized?wa=wsignin1.0) ()

And workaround is to use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) (DataContractAttribute + DataMemberAttribute)

```
var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (StaticClass.SomeType));
var obj = new StaticClass.SomeType {Int = 2};
ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);

...

static class StaticClass
{
    [DataContract]
    public class SomeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Int { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see DataContractSerializer doesn't even require `StaticClass` to be public. One difference is that you should use `WriteObject' and`ReadObject' instead `Serialize` and `Deserialize`

Answer (score 1):

Either make the class non nested or consider using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) instead.